# XML namespace prefix error after conversion to and from json

Tags: json, xml, xml-namespaces

I'm using [json.lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/) to convert from xml to json and back to xml. I need the second xml to be the same as the first one, so I use a lot of hints in the json. For example, all attributes are prefixed with '@'. Namespace declarations are also prefixed with '@'.

> {@xmlns":"..uri..","@xmlns:xsi":"..uri..","@xsi:schemaLocation":"..uri.."}

A single problem emerges when converting from the generated json to xml.

Unless I remove the 'xsi' from 'xsi:schemaLocation' by setting:

```
XMLSerializer s = new XMLSerializer();
s.setRemoveNamespacePrefixFromElements(true);
```

I get a

> nu.xom.NamespaceConflictException: Attribute prefixes must be declared.

I tried setting the namespace declaration with

```
s.setNamespace("xsi", "http://uri")
```

It didn't work.
My best guess is that I'm generating the json wrong in the first place by prefixing the namespaces like attributes, but I have no idea how to set them apart when converting. Has anyone encountered anything similar?

Comment: did you solve it?